# Azure AD get current logged in user in Java JSP API from .auth/me

Tags: java, azure, jsp, azure-active-directory

I have a simple web app with a Java API backend using JSP and Tomcat. How can I get the current logged in user (logged in via Azure AD)?

I'm trying this:

```
<%
// Fetch the data
URL url = new URL("https://myurl.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me");

Cookie cookie = null;
Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

for(int i=0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
   cookie = cookies[i];
   connection.addRequestProperty(cookie.getName(), cookie.getValue());
}

// Convert to a JSON object
JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
JsonObject rootobj = root.getAsJsonObject();

String userID = rootobj.get("user_id").getAsString();
```

But this is getting a 401 Unauthorized error. However I can get the JSON from /.auth/me in the browser - presumably because it's sending the session cookie with it. Any ideas how I can fetch that JSON from my JSP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the code you offered, I guess you want to receive the incoming cookie in the JSP and simulate the request URL `https://myurl.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me` to get JSON data.

However,you missed the `Header` part of the request, which is a necessary condition for Authentication of Azure Active Directory.

You could refer to the snippet of code as below and retry your request.

```
<%
// Fetch the data
URL url = new URL("https://myurl.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me");

Cookie cookie = null;
Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();

HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
for(int i=0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
   cookie = cookies[i];
   connection.addRequestProperty(cookie.getName(), cookie.getValue());

}
Enumeration<String> headNames = request.getHeaderNames();
while(headNames.hasMoreElements()) {
    String headerName = headNames.nextElement();
    String headerVal = request.getHeader(headerName);
    connection.addRequestProperty(headerName, headerVal);
}

out.println("generate connection.....");

connection.connect();

IOUtils.copy(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()),out);

%>
```

Hope it helps you.